# How do I efficiently debug a long-running Spark application?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a Spark application which cleans and prepares a data set, and then applies a K-means clustering algorithm onto this set. Afterwards, some metrics of the resulting clusters are calculated.

Naturally, calculating the K-means vector clusters is a task that has a long execution time. When debugging the calculation for the cluster metrics I cannot iterate quickly on my code due to the clusters being calculated on each execution. How do I solve this?

Ideas I have are:

- writing a unit test for the metric calculation methods. But it would be cumbersome to mock cluster data as
- Serialise computed K-means vector cluster data to disk

Any help is appreciated

Code for reference:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // -- start of long running execution
    val lines   = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv")
    val raw     = rawPostings(lines)
    val grouped = groupedPostings(raw)
    val scored  = scoredPostings(grouped)
    val vectors = vectorPostings(scored)
   //    assert(vectors.count() == 2121822, "Incorrect number of vectors: " + vectors.count())

    val means   = kmeans(sampleVectors(vectors), vectors, debug = true)
    // -- end of long running execution

    val results = clusterResults(means, vectors) // < -- this method operates on the result of previous ops
    printResults(results)
  }
```

Implementation of clusterResults:

```
def clusterResults(means: Array[(Int, Int)], vectors: RDD[(LangIndex, HighScore)]): Array[(String, Double, Int, Int)] = {
    // -- Note that means is quite intensive to compute
    val closest = vectors.map(p => (findClosest(p, means), p)) // -- (Int, (LangIndex, HighScore))
    val closestGrouped = closest.groupByKey() // -- (Int, Iter((LangIndex, HighScore))

    vectors.take(3).foreach(println)

    val median = closestGrouped.mapValues { vs =>
      // @todo: what does groupBy(identity) do?
      // Predef.idintity is equivalent ot x => x
      val langId: Int   = vs.map(_._1).groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1 // most common language in the cluster
      val langLabel: String = langs(langId / langSpread)
      val langPercent: Double = vs.map(_._1).count(_.equals(langId)) / vs.size // percent of the questions in the most common language (= number of questions in most common lang divided by total questions)
      val clusterSize: Int    = vs.size
      val medianScore: Int    = vs.map(_._2).

      (langLabel, langPercent, clusterSize, medianScore)
    }

    median.collect().map(_._2).sortBy(_._4)
  }
```

Comment: _Don't mock what you don't own_ but why would you even need to mock? Majority of code we use on top of high level APIs, can be easily decoupled to be tested with context running at all, and for the rest... Well this is why we have `local` mode.

Comment: With the updated code - if you want to make your code easily testable don't overuse anonymous functions. For example everything that happens in `mapValues` can be extracted and tested without using any Spark specific code. Same thing applies to `findClosest`. This way majority of error prone code can be easily tested with fast iterations.